# HOw do you uninstall Dot42

Tags: dot42

Two weeks ago I downloaded and installed Dot42AndroidSetup.exe.
There was helpful info on running Android on Hyper-V and hopeful possibilities about using VS and C# to directly target Android x86 and debug.
Since then I've seen strange behavior from an automatic update program "TallApplications.Update.exe"
There were 16 entrees in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons for the same program.
When I checked on the web, I saw that Dot42 is associated with this update service. (http://www.tallapplications.com/)
I was able to uninstall the Tallapplications from control panel, however I had to manually delete many registry entries associated with it.
If anyone knows, please tell me how to remove Dot42 without harming VS2010 or VS2012.
There are registry entrees associated with Dot42 product for both versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed the multiple entries in the Notification Area Icons which doesn't look good. You say you uninstalled 'TallApplications' - did you mean 'dot42'? What registry entries are left after uninstalling? Did you check the \Common7\IDE\Extensions folder? The dot42 folder should be gone after uninstalling. This is the dot42 integration with Visual Studio.

PS. this is not really a programming question - superuser.com or the dot42.com support area is probably a better entry.